# What is the execution order of an MVC Razor view/layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a razor layout like:

```
@using (var context = SetUpSomeContext()) {
    <div>
        Some content here
        @RenderBody();
    </div>
}
```

And a view like:

```
@{
    Layout = "MyLayout.cshtml";
}
<div>@SomethingThatDependsOnContextBeingSetUp()</div>
```

When the view renders, `SomethingThatDependsOnContextBeingSetUp` executes before `SetUpSomeContext` and fails. This seems weird, because I would expect that not to execute until `RenderBody` is called in the layout. When I switch this to use a "PageContent" section instead of RenderBody, everything works as expected. Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: My answer explains this behaviour ,what is remaining to solve?

Answer (score 23):

**The Razor pipeline is:**

1. First, Razor evaluates, if present, **_ViewStart.cshtml** that contains only Razor statements (C# or VB) for assign Layout or other initialization, it should never have html tags inside.
2. Then, it parse and evaluates **the "View" cshtml file**.
3. Then, it parse and evaluates, if present, **the Layout**, and when evaluates the `@RenderBody` method of the cshtml layout file, replaces it with the html script resulting from evaluation of "View" cshtml file.
4. Finally, it builds the html control graph objects of layout and view html files.

**So**, you cannot do depend any "Razor" objects of a view from layout operations, but rather **you may put in _ViewStart.cshtml your initialization** of objects visible to your view.

You may imagine cs(vb)html views as a static content loaded when `Controller.View` method is called.

At that point, the cshtml loaded content is parsed by Razor that evaluates the expressions (assign properties(as Layout), branchs, loops) and build a sort of binary tree or graph of "HtmlControls" objects into the `ActionResult` object returned by `View` method.

Next, ActionResult is rendered as html from Asp.Net and returned to the client as http response.

To do that, Razor parses cshtml files and carries out their code inside parts starting first from the "_ViewStart.cshtml" (also more of one if present in the sub folders chain related to the origin controller), then follows cshtml file loaded by conventions (name of view equals to the name of action in the path Views/[ControllerName]/), or by expressed view's name as parameter when calling `View` method, and finally, the eventual layout file linked to the view by `Layout` property.

Answer (score 8):

Let me clarify this by investigating a situation,Assume that you have  view like;

```
 @renderSection("Header")
    @using (var context = SetUpSomeContext()) {
        <div>
            Some content here
            @RenderBody();
        </div>
    }
   @renderSection("Footer")
```

And we are assuming that razor executes the page in the order you expect, what would happen if we declared our view like?

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<div>@SomethingThatDependsOnContextBeingSetUp()</div>
```

Razor would not have any idea whether that view needs a layout page until executing **@RenderBody()**.Also it would deduce that it rendered layout page for nothing and this would not be reasonable.So this is not what actually happens.

When request made it is so natural that Razor first executes body of your view.
If your view not specified layout like in my demo Razor only renders output of that page and stops there.If view has a layout specified like in your code 
after executing the view , it passes control to layout page.(Layout page starts to render from top to bottom)So what is remaining for Layout page is only content placement.When it sees @RenderBody() it only places output of your already executed view.

**For sections**; they are  not executed when your view body executed, after your view passes control to layout page,layout page explicitly invokes the execution of your sections in the order they are declared.

Also notice that you are specifying your page title in your view body and it is rendered in your layout title tag **(ViewBag.Title)**.After executing view body all the variables which is  declared in view body are  available in layout page.

Sum:Rendering order is from top to bottom but execution order is different.

**For your situation**: **"SomethingThatDependsOnContextBeingSetUp executes before SetUpSomeContext and fails"**. Like i said it is natural behaviour of Razor execution cycle, view body executed before  layout page executed.**When you make it section** ; view body executed first but sections are not executed before layout page.View body passes control to layout page and Layout page starts to render from top to bottom and  if it sees @RenderSection then  invokes the execution of section.So in this case SetUpSomeContext is executed before SomethingThatDependsOnContextBeingSetUp executed.

Comment: This is not an answer, and should be moved to be a part of the question.

Comment: i think it explains every detail that questioner needs to learn

Comment: This seems useful, but not much like an *answer*, more like a general tutorial.

Comment: i have just edit my answer to be more clear i think it is so obvious now

Comment: To put this more succinctly, Razor can't know you have a layout until after it has processed the main view, then it looks to see if the layout is there and processes it if it does.

Answer (score 4):

The execution order is from innermost to outermost.

I would argue that using a 'context' the way you use it is not the best design - you should consider moving the setup to the controller / action filter and pass the data to the views in model.

Comment: But sections don't follow this rule? Also, my reason for this approach is that I want to enable some common rendering functionality without requiring every controller method to change how it calls View().

Answer (score 1):

If you require some logic on all your views, create a `ViewModelBase` that all your `ViewModel`s inherit from.

Then in your `Controller(Base)` you can initialize the `ViewModel.SharedContext` and other properties.

Comment: I don't want this logic in ALL views, just in full pages. Would you still recommend using a ViewModelBase over a layout for this? Also, how can I have code run at the beginning and the end of a view using this technique (e. g. create a context and then dispose it)?

Comment: @Chase what kind of context are you talking about? Given the problems you're running into, I would suggest solving this at a different level, like I said for example using a shared ViewModel.